# 'Nothing in the world equals Dubai' - Is the use of 'equal' correct?

Tags: sentence

Is this sentence correct?

I am a bit confused about whether it is able to convey the meaning (there is no place like Dubai in the whole wide world).

Can I use 'equals' to emphasize the fact that a place is unmatched when it comes to beauty and tourism?

Thanks

Comment: It's a common pattern to imply they are the best at whatever. So yes, it is 'correct'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idiomatic sentence would be:
Nothing in the world **compares to** Dubai' -

Comment: Will this do too? - "Nothing in the world is better than Dubai"

Comment: Also you can use "can rival" instead of "compares to". @sumitkumar that's perfectly fine as well

Comment: "Nothing in the world is equal to Dubai" or "Nothing in the world can be compared to Dubai'

Comment: @Thanveer: what is you like about all these auxiliary verbs? They weaken the sentence. *Nothing in the world **equals** Dubai. Nothing in the world **compares to** Dubai. Nothing in the world **rivals** Dubai* They all work. And they're better than *is equal to, can compare to, can rival*.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct and basically unremarkable.

It is equivalent to "In the whole world, Dubai is without equal."